# Functions output is not updating after a minute even though it have to

Tags: javascript

my JavaScript below is showing the current time. In this regard I want that my code is showing every new second when it is time for. when it is time for updating time the start time is displayed again in the console but not the updated time. What I am doing wrong?

```
 //current Date
  function formateDate(dateObject) {
     parts = {
      ms: dateObject.getMilliseconds(),
      seconds: dateObject.getSeconds(),
      minutes: dateObject.getMinutes(),
      hours: dateObject.getUTCHours() + 2,
      day: dateObject.getDay(),
      date: dateObject.getDate(),
      month: dateObject.getMonth() + 1,
      year: dateObject.getFullYear(),
    };
    //appending zero to Date and Month if required
    pD = parts.date < 10 ? "0" + parts.date : parts.date;
    pM = parts.month < 10 ? "0" + parts.month : parts.month;

    pHours = parts.hours < 10 ? "0" + parts.hours : parts.hours;
    pMin = parts.minutes < 10 ? "0" + parts.minutes : parts.minutes;
    
    //convert the numbers of Day into the name of weekday:
    //Array for Weekday-names
    const weekDays = [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
    ];

    for (let daysNumber = 0; daysNumber <= parts.day; daysNumber++) {
      if (daysNumber === parts.day) {
        currentDayName = weekDays[daysNumber];
        break;
      }
    }
    return `${currentDayName}, ${pD}.${pM}.${parts.year} ${parts.hours}:${pMin}:${parts.seconds}:${parts.ms}`;
  }

  const myDate = new Date();
  const myDateFormatted = formateDate(myDate);
  remainingSec = 60000 - (parts.seconds * 1000);
  console.log(remainingSec)
  
 console.log(myDateFormatted)
 setInterval( () => {
     console.log(myDateFormatted)
 },remainingSec)
```

Comment: Why are you mixing-up UTC and Local values? You're using `getUTCHours()` but then do `getDay()` and `getMinutes()`... why?

Comment: because the compiler I use is not showing the right hour with getHours()

Comment: At the bottom you have `remainingSec = 60000 - (parts.seconds * 1000);` <-- This won't work because `parts` is defined _inside_ the `formateDate` function.

Comment: It is actually working because parts is global. The only problem is that the output will be showed again every pending second  but not with updated time

Comment: You need to recalculate `myDateFormatted` to see an updated value.

Comment: @digitalbreed how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move variables `myDate` and `myDateFormatted` to `setInterval`:

```
let myDate = new Date();
let myDateFormatted = formateDate(myDate);

console.log({ myDateFormatted });

remainingSec = 60000 - parts.seconds * 1000;

console.log({ remainingSec })

setInterval(() => {
  myDate = new Date();
  myDateFormatted = formateDate(myDate);

  console.log({ myDateFormatted });
}, remainingSec);
```